# Thunderbird forwarding drafts

Tags: thunderbird

I have a filter on Thunderbird that forwards all my income email to my Gmail account. This filter is set up to:

- "Match all messages"
- Forward them to my Gmail account
- Run on my inbox
- Mark the messages as unread

However, I have noticed that it also **forwards my drafts** as I am editing emails that I am about to send.

Comment: Do you store your drafts in the Inbox folder? Or maybe a subfolder?

Comment: Thanks @GurkenPapst How do I check that?

Comment: Create a new draft, save it and check all your folders. You should be able to locate the new draft in one of them. You could also go to `Tools | Account Settings | <account name> | Copies & Folders` to find out where Thunderbird saves (or at least should save) drafts.